# Displaying an alert view similar to UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, awakefromnib

I am trying to create a custom "alert view", nothing too fancy I just want to display a view overtop of the current view just like a UIAlertView.

Now here is the problem...I made the view in a nib file and now I want to alloc/init the view whenever I need to present an alert.Can anyone help me?

This is my attempt to get the view initialized...as of right now this crashes my app when I alloc/init a new alert view.

The app is crashing by telling me the view is not key-value compliant for the outlets.. I definitely have the outlets hooked up properly, unless I have a "File's Owner" thing screwed up.

NSObject 0x14e49800> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key....

```
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
            self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
            if (self) {
                [self load];
            }
            return self;
        }

- (void)load {
    NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil];
    [self addSubview:[views firstObject]];
}

    - (void)awakeFromNib {
        [super awakeFromNib];

    }

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil][0];
        if (self) {
            [self addSubview:self.contentView];
            self.frame = frame;
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                          message:(NSString *)message
                         delegate:(id)delegate
                cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
               confirmButtonTitle:(NSString *)confirmButtonTitle {
        self = [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
        if (self) {

        }
        return self;
    }
```

I made this method to present the view, just a simple addSubview...

```
- (void)showInView:(UIView *)view {
    [view addSubview:self];

}
```

Comment: 1) What class does your AlertView extend? Is it UIView, UIViewController?
2) What is the code you are calling to initialise it? Is it simply: yourAlertView = [[YourAlertView alloc] init];?
3) What is the error message shown?

Comment: It is a subclass of UIView, and I want to be able to go yourAlertView = [[YourAlertView alloc] init]. The problem is that the frame of the view is CGRectZero no matter what I do. I was able to get it to run though, but just nothing happens when I call showInView:

Comment: Just as an afterthought, have you set the File's Owner to self in Interface Builder, and in your loadNibNamed function call? Also, manually set the frame to your required size.

Comment: Yes I did set the files owner..as to setting the frame I attempted to do that in my code above? Did I do it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling autolayout and run the code.

Comment: Seems like IOS 7 has disabled addSubview method on UIAlertView

Comment: I am not using UIAlertView, I am making a custom view that mimics it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class same as below

```
#import "MyOverLay.h"

@interface MyOverLay (){
    // control declarations
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activitySpinner;
    UILabel *loadingLabel;
}

@end

@implementation AcuOverLay


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)show:(NSString *)message{
    // configurable bits
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.alpha = 0.75f;
    self.autoresizingMask =UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    float labelHeight = 22;
    float labelWidth = self.frame.size.width - 20;

    // derive the center x and y
    float centerX = self.frame.size.width / 2;
    float centerY = self.frame.size.height / 2;

    // create the activity spinner, center it horizontall and put it 5 points above center x
    activitySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activitySpinner.frame = CGRectMake(centerX - (activitySpinner.frame.size.width / 2) , centerY - activitySpinner.frame.size.height - 20, activitySpinner.frame.size.width, activitySpinner.frame.size.height);

    activitySpinner.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self addSubview:activitySpinner];

    [activitySpinner startAnimating];

    // create and configure the "Loading Data" label
    loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(centerX - (labelWidth / 2), centerY + 20 , labelWidth, labelHeight)];


    loadingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    loadingLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    loadingLabel.text = message;
    loadingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    loadingLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self addSubview:loadingLabel];

}

- (void)hide{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.alpha = 0;
        [self removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}


@end
```

then create instance wherever you want

```
loadingOverlay = [[MyOverLay alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        loadingOverlay.tag = 999;
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:loadingOverlay];
        [loadingOverlay show:@"Saving ..."];
```

Comment: That is ideally what I want, but the frame of the view is always CGRectZero because I alloc/init the view in code, not from another nib. This is the problem I need solved (if its even possible)

Comment: Sadly the frame is still CGRectZero even if I do that.

Comment: Since this is a layout done in code I assume the above code would work totally fine, but loading a view from a nib throws some complications into the mix, thats what I am struggling with.